# rails 4 , simple_form , nested model bootstrap tabs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I am using `rails4` with`bootstrap` and `simple_form` for nested model. I would like to render fields for Order object into different tab using `tabs bootstrap`. 
Here is my `simple_form` :

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="#course" data-toggle="tab">Customer Form </a></li>
    <li><a href="#module1" data-toggle="tab">Order Forms</a></li>
    <li><a href="#module2" data-toggle="tab">Module2</a></li>    
</ul>
<ul class="tab-content">
    <li class="tab-pane active" id="course">
         <%= simple_form_for @customer,:html=>{:class => 'form-horizontal' }  do |f| %>
         <%= f.input :first_name,  :hint =>   'First Name' %>
         <%= f.input :last_name,  :hint => 'Last Name' %>
         <%= f.input :email, :label => false, :hint => 'Email' %>
         <%= f.input :address, :hint => 'Address' %>
         <%= f.input :customer_number, :hint => 'Customer Number'  %>
         <%= f.input :birthday, :as => :string,:label => false, :hint => 'Birthday'  %>   
    </li>
    <li class="tab-pane" id="module1">                   
         <%= f.simple_fields_for :orders do |builder| %>
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">    
    <li><a href="#module1-step1" data-toggle="tab"><%= "#" %></a></li>
 <ul class="tab-content">
    <li class="tab-pane active" id="module1-step1">
                <p><%= render 'order_fields' , :f => builder %></p>
    </li>
 </ul>
                 <% end %>
 </ul>
```

I can not get it work in a proper way. Indeed it does not make `tabs` in order. 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

On line 6: `<ul class="tab-content">` should be a `div`. All the `li` tags nested should also be `div`. Please see the [Bootstrap page](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) and you will find the structure:

```
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
  <li><a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
</div>
```

Try fixing that first to see if it works :) I am not very sure if they allow these tabs to be nested like your solution but just give it a try first.